# Count number of records totalling a given percentage of the overall total in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm relatively new to power bi so please bear with me!

I have a report which looks at information about individual stores of a given customer.

One of the requirements is to show the % that the top N stores constitute to the overall total, for example the top 1 store makes up 30% of overall sales, top 5 stores make up 65% of the overall total, etc. I can achieve this easily using the 'Top N' filter function.

The other requirement is to count the number of stores which total 80% of the overall total sales. For example, we have a total of 100 stores for a given account which generate a revenue of £10,000. The top 60 stores generate a revenue of £8,000, therefore 60 of the 100 stores make up 80% of the overall sales.

Hopefully that makes sense! Is this possible within power bi? If so could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This could get complicated (e.g. if 60 stores = £7,999.99, then is 80% 61 stores?). But Jacob's answer on this forum post should get you going in the right direction. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b13a8ce5-c77d-43c2-8be4-7e300e02cdbc/count-clients-that-make-80-total-sales?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel

Comment: There's also a percentile visual available in PBI which could help? I don't know if you want the exact number that makes up 80% or the whole percentile graph? https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/visual-awesomeness-unlocked-percentile-chart/. Have a look [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/percentile-calculation/td-p/24933) for a percentile calculation in DAX.